# Remove lines that contain specific string

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following text and I want to remove line that only contains "&nbsp;" (i.e. remove first and last line but keep the third line) using JavaScript?

**Original:**

```
&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;
&lt;br>     
&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp; ABCDEF
&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;
```

**Desired result:**

```
&lt;br>      
&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp; ABCDEF
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve your issue?

Comment: Do you have those `<br>`s in your code or you just added them to break the line here?

Comment: I think we will need to see some code to understand the context surrounding this question. It is too difficult to understand exactly what you need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a shot:

```
var output = str.replace(/(?:^|\r?\n)(?:&amp;nbsp;)*?(?=$|\r?\n)/g, '');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a6sZN/1/)

Also, in case you want to keep lines without any text replace `*` by `+`. That is, considering this input text:

```
foo
&amp;nbsp;

baz
```

The first regex would remove the empty line:

```
foo
baz
```

While `/(?:^|\r?\n)(?:&amp;nbsp;)+?(?=$|\r?\n)/g` keeps it:

```
foo

baz
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it:

```
function cleanLines(s) {
var x = s.match(/[^\r\n]*/g), i, y;
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
y = x[i].replace(/\s*&nbsp;\s*/g, '');
if (y.length == 0)
x[i] = y;
else
x[i] = x[i] + '\n'; /* or \r\n if you want 30-year obsolete typewriter carriage returns */
}
return x.join('');
}
```

Run the function `cleanLines(inputString)` to obtain a return value with all the lines deleted that you don't want.